# Why use computed properties to assign an image?

Tags: swift, computed-properties

In [Apple's SwiftUI tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/building-lists-and-navigation), I see this example:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct Landmark: Hashable, Codable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var park: String
    var state: String
    var description: String

    private var imageName: String
    var image: Image {
        Image(imageName)
    }
}
```

Why does it use a computed property to assign the image? Why not just do:

```
var image: Image = Image(imageName)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why does it use a computed property to assign the image? Why not just do:
> `var image: Image = Image(imageName)`

By doing this you will get this compile error.

[image]

**Cannot use instance member 'imageName' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available**

It means you can not initialize properties that are at self-level. You can't initialize properties that depend on each other.

Comment: You should probably mention that you can initialize properties that depend on each other, but you need a designated initializer which is often omitted for coding comfort (you loose the default initializer, you have to assign all the values manually, e.t.c.)